# Awk convert csv to xml optionnal tag and rename tag

Tags: xml, csv, awk

```
name;num_tel;num_fixe;id_client;num_comd;email;city;date_liv
gwenael;0998452223;1038431234;50C;12345;gwa@yahoo.fr;London;08/07/2015
judith;0954674487;1045227937;23D;78965;judith@yahoo.fr;Toulouse;11/05/2015
```

from this csv i generate in output this xml using awk command.
I need help for 2 problems.
tag name (name;num_tel;num_fixe;id_client;num_comd;email;) are the default value of the csv
and  city;date_liv had been added by user before they generate the csv and they can add more tag after the default tag.
my objective is  to output all the optionals tags  in my xml , once they had been input in the csv
i try to use loop for but i have so many mistakes i need help to do it.
I started at position 7 because optional tag start at that place until the end.

```
NF==1 for (i=7;i<=NF;i++)
    { 
        printf " <option>%s</option>\n"
            printf " <val>%s</val>\n"
    }
```

secondly  how can i rename a tag for exemple num_tel to  cell phone in my awk script  ?

```
<rows>
 <C>
    <client> 
                <identity>              
                            <name> gwenael </name>

                                <M>
                                        <num_fixe> 0998452223 </num_fixe>
                                        <contact>
                                                <cell phone>1038431234 </cell phone>   <!--num_tel--!>
                                        </contact>  

                                        <option>city</option>       
                                        <value>London </value>
                                        <option>date_liv</option>
                                        <value>08/07/2015</value>

                                        <num_comd> 12345</num_comd>
                                </M>                                    
                </identity>
                                        <date_liv>08/07/2015</date_liv>
            <locomotion>car</locomotion>
</client>
</C>

<D>
    <pro> 
                <identity>              
                            <name> judith </name>

                                <id_client>23D</id_client>

                                <option>city</option>       
                                <value>Paris </value>
                                <option>date_liv</option>
                                <value>08/05/2015</value>

                                        <num_fixe> 0998452223 </num_fixe>
                            <company>
                                <num_fixe>1045227937</num_fixe>
                            </company>  
                                        <num_comd> 12345</num_comd>                                   
                </identity>
                                        <date_liv>08/07/2015</date_liv>
            <locomotion>car</locomotion>
    </pro>
</D>
```

Comment: There are some unexplained parts in your output. For example, how do we get `<C: id_client =50C>` from the input? Is this supposed to be a `C` tag? You have a closing `</C>` so I guess it should be. The XML for the two different rows has a completely different structure. Please [edit] your question to tidy it up and provide a clear, consistent desired output.

Comment: Sorry i did not precise that the C and D groups are based on the id_client the string. In fact <C: id_client =50C> in the xml appear as <C=50C>. and in group C tag name output are not the same in group D.    But do not worry about this i already take care of that in my awk script. the main problems is about the optional tag and change the name of a tag. If you have over question please i'am here thank you

Comment: `<C=50C>` is invalid XML! If it is unrelated to your question, perhaps you should remove it anyway and focus on the part you want.

Comment: ok i remove it, but some times i have answer where we told me "give more details" so that what i did but it is not related to my question it is just to show the structure of what i'am doing

Comment: i really  learned for all the answer  i receive  step by step. You are right when you said i dont clearly explain my problems i'am sorry for that. it's due to the fact that information come to me by user little by little so i couldn't explain it clearly to. i can show you how i made my script based on what you gave to me, i understand you are pissed about that and i'am really sorry. awk is really different from what i know

Comment: @iceman255 : Google for "awk one liners explained" and spend an hour or two reading thru them. That said, anything more than 80 chars shouldn't be considered a one liner, and should be formatted so the structure is apparent! ;-)

Comment: Please don't remove your question by posting a solution in its place. You can add your solution as an answer (there is an Answer your own question option for this). If it is not a full solution, you should ask a new question with the new problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focusing on the problem of adding the custom fields to your output, you could use something like this. You will need to insert these parts into your script in the appropriate places:

```
# set field separator
BEGIN { FS=";" }

# first line
NR == 1 {
    for (i=7; i<=NF; ++i) a[i] = $i # store field headers in array a
    next                            # skip to next line
}

# all other lines
{
    # print values along with the matching name from the array
    for (i=7; i<=NF; ++i) printf "<option>%s</option><value>%s</value>", a[i], $i
}
```

Your desired output format isn't clear so I didn't use any formatting characters in the code but you could add a newline after each `<option>`-`<value>` pair in the loop using the built-in `ORS` (Output Record Separator) variable:

```
printf "<option>%s</option><value>%s</value>%s", a[i], $i, ORS
```

The advantage of using `ORS` rather than `\n` is that it is platform-independent, meaning that the code should work on files that use DOS line endings in Windows or UNIX line endings on other systems.